# when checkbox field is marked as true at that instant ,display an alert message(popup with some text) before pressing save button

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to display an alert message at the instant when the checkbox is ticked. I had a VF code but the problem was- alert message display only after clicking standard save button. Plz, help me on this issue.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" rendered="{!(Opportunity.Forecast_Indicator__c)}">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.alert("By clicking OK, you have verified the ship date, Sku, and quantity as that is what will be forecasted.  If not, please go back and verify before moving forward");
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Can you add the checkbox field too tag in the code?  You need to call the alert message onclick event of that checkbox field

Answer (score -1):

Haven't tested this but...

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="name" onchange="showAlert(this);"/>
```

**JS Code:**

```
function showAlert(element) {
  var isSelected = $(element).is(":checked");
  if (isSelected) {
      alert('your text);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help, but this code is not working for my scenario.